# How to show loading animation in a view - IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I have a view in which I want to show loading animation. I have seen some application they are showing circular image to show loading, and the action will happen on background, Same thing I want to achieve here, Any inbuilt animation is available in IOS?

TIA

Comment: You can simply use the UIActivityIndicator is you simply want to show a loading process...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the built in activity indicator.

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *indicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
indicator.center = CGPointMake(alert.bounds.size.width / 2 , (alert.bounds.size.height) /2);
[indicator startAnimating];
```

simply add it as a subview in to your view.

Comment: Great answer. I suggest adding something like:  [self.view addSubview:indicator];  Even though you stated to 'simply add it as a subview in to your view'

Comment: @helloGo I prefer to keep it as a comment, one may want to add an indicator not directly to the `self.view` on some other view or subview

Answer (score 3):

You may use the UIActivityIndicator if you want to keep things simple. Or there are plenty of open source activity indicators that do a lot of fancy stuff in addition to just showing a spinning wheel. [MBProgressHUD](https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD/) and [SVProgressHUD](https://github.com/samvermette/SVProgressHUD/) are two neat implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Create YourViewController, and then add the the MBProgressHUB library to your project (you can get the library from [here](http://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD)); download the project and move the library to your project.

Then you can use the following code to achieve your task:

**YourViewController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MBProgressHUD.h"

@interface YourViewController : UITableViewController <MBProgressHUDDelegate>
{
    MBProgressHUD *hud;
}
```

**YourViewController.m**

```
#import "YourViewController.h"
@interface YourViewController ()
@end

@implementation YourViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self initializeProgressLoading];
    [self getObjects];
    [hud hide:YES afterDelay:1];
}

-(void) initializeProgressLoading {
    hud = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.navigationController.view];
    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:hud];
    hud.delegate = self;
    hud.labelText = @"Loading";
    [hud showWhileExecuting:@selector(sleep) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}

- (void)sleep {
    sleep(50000);
}

- (void) getObjects {
// connect to db and get all objects
//you can write any thing here
}

- (void)hudWasHidden:(MBProgressHUD *)hud1 {
    // Remove HUD from screen when the HUD was hidded
    [hud removeFromSuperview];
    hud = nil;
}
```